# Relationship (if any) between h-principle and homotopy analysis method

Tags: partial-differential-equations, homotopy-theory, h-principle

This *might* be a soft question, and may also demonstrate some misunderstanding on my part.

M. Gromov's [$h$-principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_principle) is a powerful characterization on when general classes of PDEs and PDRs (specifically under-determined ones) admit solutions. Specifically if a problem admits the h-principle generic solutions can be deformed to true (holonomic) solutions.

Now we have a very similar sounding semi-analytical method of solving PDEs called [homotopy analysis method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_analysis_method) which given an initial guess solution uses series expansion and homotopy methods to converge to solutions.

I understand the two methods are of completely different flavors, **but I was wondering if there is any relationship between these two methods**?  My gut instinct would be that the second can be interpreted as a special case of the first, but I couldn't find any resources that made any connections whatsoever, so they might not be related.